# Ordenar alfabéticamente un ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collection

Tengo el código:

```
private ArrayList<Casa> casas = new ArrayList<Casa>();
```

Y cuando agregue los datos quiero que se agreguen ordenados alfabéticamente.

He intentado con

```
Collection.sort(casas);
```

Pero me sale un error así:

Required type: List <T

Provided: ArrayList<Casa

Y no sé como resolverlo.

Comment: ¿El objeto casa implementa `Comparable`? Si no lo implementa es obvio el error, ¿Cómo java va a imaginar por qué propiedad del objeto ordenar? `Collection.sort` necesita que el tipo de la colección o bien implemente `Comparable` o que suministres un `Comparator`. Incluye la implementación del tipo `Casa` y cómo esperas que se ordenen para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Probé con un ArrayList de String normal y funciona cuando pongo `Collections.sort(casas);` pero no funciona cuando pongo `Collection.sort(casas);` intenta eso por favor.

Comment: No lo podía hacer con el String porque me lo utilizo como objeto, igual ya encontraron la respuesta, agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) para ordenar alfabéticamente por algún atributo de tu clase Casa

Ejemplo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Casa{

private String tipo;
private double precio;

public Casa(String tipo,double precio){
this.tipo=tipo;
this.precio=precio;
}

 
public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}
  
public double getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}
 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
Casa casa1=new Casa("Prefabricada",2570.30);
Casa casa2=new Casa("Amueblada",3540.70);
Casa casa3=new Casa("Betada",4540.70);


List <Casa> casas=new ArrayList<>();

casas.add(casa1);
casas.add(casa2);
casas.add(casa3);
//Ordenamos alfabeticamente por tipo
Comparator<Casa> comparador= Comparator.comparing(Casa::getTipo);

List<Casa>listaPrincipal=casas.stream().sorted(comparador).collect(Collectors.toList());

for (Casa c:listaPrincipal) {
    System.out.println(c.getTipo());
    System.out.println(c.getPrecio());
}

}
```

salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí me funcionó, te lo agradezco mucho de verdad, quedó tal cual como lo quería.

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta dale visto bueno dando click en el check-in ✓